# Map iterator issues. Code included

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

So here s all my code, I dont really understand why I'm getting these errors.
The issue is within the export recipes function.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<string>


using namespace std;

void DisplayMenu();
void AddRecipe( map< string, vector<string> >& recipes );
void ExportRecipes( map< string, vector<string> >& recipes );

int main ( void ){

   int choice = 0;
   bool done = false;
   map< string, vector<string> > recipes;

    while ( done == false ){
       DisplayMenu();
       cin >> choice;

       if ( choice == 3 ){
        done = true;
       }
       else if ( choice == 2 ){
        ExportRecipes( recipes );
       }
       else if ( choice == 1 ){
        AddRecipe( recipes );
       }

    }
}

void DisplayMenu(){ 
   cout << "1. Add Recipe " << endl;
   cout << "2. Export Recipes " << endl;
   cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
}

void AddRecipe( map< string, vector<string> >& recipes ){

   string name, ingredient;
   bool done = false;
   cout << "Enter recipe name: ";
   cin >> name;
   while ( done == false ){     
       cout  << "Enter new ingredient and amount( enter done to exit )" << endl;
       getline( cin , ingredient, '\n' );

       if ( ingredient == "done" ){
           done = true;
       }

       if( ingredient != "done"){
           recipes[ name ].push_back( ingredient );
           cout << "Added \"" << ingredient << "\"." << endl << endl;
       }        
   }
}


void ExportRecipes(  map< string, vector<string> >&recipes ){

   ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open( "Recipes.txt" );

   for ( map< string, vector<string> >::iterator recipe =
       recipes.begin(); recipe != recipes.end(); recipe++ ) {
       outFile << endl << endl << recipe -> first << endl;

       for ( map< string, vector<string> >::iterator ingredients = 
           recipe->second.begin(); ingredients != recipe->second.end();
            ingredients++ ) {
               outFile << "\t" << *ingredients << endl;
       }
   }
}
```

If I only iterate through the first for loop in export I can get the key, but I cant get the value at all.

Comment: What is the "issue"? I'm not sure what you mean with that last sentence.

Comment: I can't access the data in the ingredients iterator.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>' c:\users\jason\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\assignment 5\assignment 5\source.cpp 89

Comment: Awesome, I switched it up and it now works!

Comment: @Fox Why did you edit the code to give it such strange indents?

Comment: @ean5533 sorry forgot to indent first 3 lines in main .. :P

Comment: -1 _'All your code'_ is obviously too much ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have the second for loop with Map. recipe->second is a vector so try this -

```
void ExportRecipes(  map< string, vector<string> >&recipes ){
   ofstream outFile;
   outFile.open( "Recipes.txt" );

   for ( map< string, vector<string> >::iterator recipe =
       recipes.begin();
        recipe != recipes.end();
        recipe++ )
   {
      outFile << endl << endl << recipe -> first << endl;

      for ( vector<string>::iterator ingredients = 
        recipe->second.begin();
            ingredients != recipe->second.end();
            ingredients++ )
        {
            outFile << "\t" << *ingredients << endl;
        }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( map< string, vector<string> >::iterator ingredients = 
        recipe->second.begin();
```

`recipe->second` is `vector<string>`. Therefore, `recipe->second.begin()` returns `vector<string>::iterator`, not `map< string, vector<string> >::iterator`